# Saving multiple documents at once - Mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save

```
user.save(function (err){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        admin.save(function (err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }else{
                res.redirect('/home');
            }
       });
    }
});
```

This doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how to save multiple documents at once? Are there any other modules I could use except for mongoose to save them all? Thank you.

I also tried this:

```
user.save(function (err){
     if(err)
        throw err;
     next();
});
admin.save(function (err){
     if(err)
        throw err;
     res.redirect('/home');
});
```

But that didn't work either! Thanks again for your help

Comment: The top one should work as long as they are both mongoose documents.

Comment: How do you now that it doesn't work, what kind of errors do you get? How did you check the flow of your code?

Comment: The error I get is "Can't set headers after they are sent". I tried having only the first save function, called, and it worked and I also tried having only the second save function, called, and it worked again (I have tried this for both ways I wrote, but I still get the same error!). BUT the thing is.... both documents get saved, but the server crashes (and i get the error above) and it doesn't redirect me to '/home', so I have to restart the server for it to run again.

Comment: Sorry, the first one doesn't work!

Comment: Can you paste the code of the whole route? The error that you're getting is most likely related to the fact that you're making a call to the 'res' object more than once.

Answer (score -1):

```
app.post('/homeUser', function (req, res, next) {
            user.findOne({'accountOwner': req.user.userdata.username}, function (err, user){
                if(err)
                    throw err;
                if(user){
                    console.log('user found');
                    user.userdata.username = req.body.newUserName; // I have some other variables as well but they don't matter
                    user.save(function (err){
                        if(err)
                            throw err;
                        res.redirect('/home');
                    });
                } else if(!user) {
                    console.log('new user');
                    var newUser = new user();
                    //setting up some values for the newUser and some for the req.user
                    newUser.save(function (err){
                        if(err){
                            throw err;
                        }else{
                            req.user.save(function (err){ // the problem is here
                                if(err){
                                    throw err;
                                }else{
                                    res.redirect('/home');
                                }
                           });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    }
```

The error is at else{ req.user.save(function (err){ or at least at that line.
(sorry if there are any spelling errors, I wrote this code just now, because I'm not using the computer for coding, but this is pretty much the code (except for some semicolons and curly brackets!))